# Issue with how the site displays on Chrome

Tags: bug, design, css

Attached screenshot of the review queue, under the Windows version of Chrome. I'm unable to see the bottom stuff in the panel. If I scroll down/up, I see more of it, but never the whole thing.

[image]

Comment: Does this happen for you also on normal question pages, if you drag the flag popup downwards? Because it doesn't for me (Chromium 32 / Linux), and I can't rest it in the review view due to insufficient rep on this site.

Comment: Not just Chrome; I'm seeing this on Firefox.

Comment: Issue still exists...